Implicit conversion of subtypes not recognized by Scala 3 compiler
I have the following code:
enum Value {
  case Nil
  case Boolean(value: scala.Boolean)
  case Number(value: Double)
  case String(value: String)
}

object Value {
  given Conversion[scala.Boolean, Boolean] with
    override def apply(x: scala.Boolean): Boolean = Boolean(x)

  given [T <: Double]: Conversion[T, Value] with
    override def apply(x: T): Value = Value.Number(x.asInstanceOf[Double])
}

when trying to implicitly convert, for instance, an Int into a Value, like so:
val n: Int = 5
val nv: Value = n

the compiler complains that it found Int where Value is required.
If I supply a name to the implicit conversion, say F, the compiler would accept val nv = Value.F(n), as expected, but it is not the desired result.

Int is not really a subtype of Double, so you need to add another conversion. You may use the Numeric typeclass to write a generic conversion from anything that is like a number into a Value.Number - BTW, my personal advice, don't write code like this, this will be a nightmare to debug and understand. - Rather, add two extensions asValue and asScala or something to convert back-and-forth in a more explicit way but still not fully explicit.
